# Error trying to access Sharepoint Online host web list data from provider hosted add-in part using JSOM CDL

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I've looked all over the internet for the answer to this, and still cannot figure it out.  There are many examples CLOSE to what I'm trying to do, but none that actually are exact.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a provider hosted Sharepoint Add-In that has an aspx page with C# codebehind.  I also have a javascript file in the provider hosted side (web side, NOT the app-web) that I'm trying to use to access some List data from the host web.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var customWP_NewsAndInfo_allArticles;
var hostweburl;
var addinweburl;

    // This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Get the URI decoded URLs.
        hostweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
        );
        addinweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
        );

        // resources are in URLs in the form:
        // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
        var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

        // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
            function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js",
                    function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", customWP_NewsAndInfo_retrieveListItems); }
                    );
            }
            );
    });


function customWP_NewsAndInfo_retrieveListItems() {
        // get parameters from the query string for add-in part properties
        var sourceList = 'News and Information';


        // context: The ClientContext object provides access to
        //      the web and lists objects.
        // factory: Initialize the factory object with the
        //      app web URL.
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(addinweburl);
        var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(addinweburl);
        clientContext.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
        var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);

        this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
        clientContext.load(this.web);

        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle(sourceList);

        var items = oList.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
        var includeExpr = 'Include(Title)';
        clientContext.load(items, includeExpr);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.customWP_NewsAndInfo_onQuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.customWP_NewsAndInfo_onQueryFailed)
        );
}
```

I don't need to show the success and failure functions since it never reaches those.  When it runs executeQueryAsync, it always comes back with this error and stack trace:

```
MicrosoftAjax.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Array.<anonymous> (MicrosoftAjax.js:5)
    at MicrosoftAjax.js:5
    at SP.ClientRequest.$3I_0 (SP.Runtime.js?_=1493695027549:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (MicrosoftAjax.js:5)
    at MicrosoftAjax.js:5
    at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (MicrosoftAjax.js:5)
    at SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutor.$1W_1 (SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1493695027551:2)
    at Function.SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorInternal.processSuccessCallback (SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1493695027551:2)
    at SP.RequestInfo.success (SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1493695027551:2)
    at SP.RequestExecutor.internalOnMessage (SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1493695027551:2)
```

I even tried troubleshooting by trying a Sharepoint Hosted add-in but I get a very similar error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd?d=NmWpgseF5Lm2ObZqsFB7X8Sc_FI92_ZNS_ucNmpXp96dB8TO5HMUZeqx3R5ocUw8b6hyk9AKxItxXJ…:5)
    at ScriptResource.axd?d=NmWpgseF5Lm2ObZqsFB7X8Sc_FI92_ZNS_ucNmpXp96dB8TO5HMUZeqx3R5ocUw8b6hyk9AKxItxXJ…:5
    at SP.ClientRequest.$x_0 (SP.Runtime.js?_=1493693899820:2)
    at SP.ClientRequest.$3I_0 (SP.Runtime.js?_=1493693899820:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd?d=NmWpgseF5Lm2ObZqsFB7X8Sc_FI92_ZNS_ucNmpXp96dB8TO5HMUZeqx3R5ocUw8b6hyk9AKxItxXJ…:5)
    at ScriptResource.axd?d=NmWpgseF5Lm2ObZqsFB7X8Sc_FI92_ZNS_ucNmpXp96dB8TO5HMUZeqx3R5ocUw8b6hyk9AKxItxXJ…:5
    at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (ScriptResource.axd?d=NmWpgseF5Lm2ObZqsFB7X8Sc_FI92_ZNS_ucNmpXp96dB8TO5HMUZeqx3R5ocUw8b6hyk9AKxItxXJ…:5)
    at SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutor.$1W_1 (SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1493693899822:2)
    at Function.SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorInternal.processSuccessCallback (SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1493693899822:2)
    at SP.RequestInfo.success (SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1493693899822:2)
```

I tried creating a custom list called "testing" and just used `'Include(Title)'` but I received the same error.  I tried inserting `debugger;` and stepping through the code using Chrome Developer tools but it's hard to read the obfuscated Microsoft code.  Any help on figuring this out would be hugely appreciated!  Thanks a lot ahead of time!

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this issue by using [this code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/SharePoint-Add-in-JSOM-CrossDomain) and working my way back from it, since it worked when I ran it.  I finally found the problem to be the call:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
```

When I compared to the github example, their call was like this:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
```

**When I took out the Function.createDelegate part and just used the syntax they used, the error went away and I'm now able to load the list items!**

As far as why this would be, maybe someone can shed some more light on this for us than I can?  All I know is that whatever I tried, even testing on a Sharepoint Hosted add-in instead of Provider Hosted, it never worked until I changed this code.  Now I can use Sharepoint JSOM using the Cross Domain Library on my Provider Hosted add-in on the web side.  This is very valuable to me, especially when working with Publishing Images because of the limitations in this area with REST.  I knew I could use REST instead in my case, but unfortunately, REST calls don't work well for my situation, since I'm also getting a Publishing Image column (Type="Image") and using REST you have to make a separate call for each list item.

I really hope this helps someone else in my position and saves you the hours I spent tracking this down!

Cheers!

Paul